# Tell flake8 to ignore a few consecutive lines

Tags: python-3.x, flake8, pyflakes

I'm writing a game which involves a predefined table that looks like this:

```
SCORES = [
    [   1, 123,   0, 456],
    [  78,  90,  -1, 234],
    [ 567,   8,  90,  12],
    [   3,   4, 567, 890]
]
```

To no one's surprise, `flake8` gets angry about it. I know I can add `# noqa` for these lines, but I have several similar tables and they're actually much larger than 4*4. It would be best to have something like

```
# noqa-start

my_ugly_tables

# noqa-end

def regular_function_that_should_be_checked():
    pass
```

I'm using flake8 3.5.0 on Python 3.6. Any chance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flake8 disable linter only for a block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428794/flake8-disable-linter-only-for-a-block-of-code)